# PySpark: custom function in aggregation on grouped data

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame containing things as

```
Row(id='id1', type='A', status='H', keywords=['k1', 'k2', 'k3'])
```

Status is a binary option ('S'/'H').
what I need to do is counting the ratio of occurrences in status *S* per each keyword per type, id and status. 
Ratio will be

```
s/(s+h)
```

where *s* and *h* here are the occurrences.
So for instance, if keyword *k1* occurs 2 times as S and 3 times as H in type *A* I'll want 2/3 for it in that type and my final output would ideally be

```
Row(id='id1', type='A', keyword='k1', ratio=0.66)
```

I was thinking this has to pass through several steps, and I'd be happy with computing the occurrences in S and H and then creating further column to ratio the two.

But how would I compute the said occurrences after I run a *groupBy* by 'id', 'type' and 'status'? Would there be a way to run an *agg* with a custom function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, avg, col

ratio = avg(
    # If status "S" then 1.0 else 0.0
    (col("status") == "S").cast("double")
 ).alias("ratio")

(df
    .withColumn("keyword", explode("keywords"))
    .groupBy("id", "type", "keyword")
    .agg(ratio))
```